# ASP.NET MVC - How to keep collections value when calls an Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I fill these items on screen with a `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, new SelectList(...))`.

Ok, but when I call any action which receives this ViewModel, I got this collection empty.
Is there a way to get back the DropDownList values when I call any action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a normal behavior and it's how HTML works. Only the selected value of a `<select>` element is sent to the server, not the entire collection. In your POST action if you want to retrieve the collection all you have to do is exactly the same you did in your GET action to retrieve it in the first place. That's usually a database call. And if you are afraid that you might be hitting your database quite often, just cache the collection.

Comment: Cool. Hitting the database a several times made my performance bad. Cache is a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a tag `form` you can only send the value selected in the tag `select`, in this case the value of `SelectedItem`.
If you need also send the list of values ​​of `Items`, you have to create something like this:

```
@{
   var ind = 0;
   foreach(var item in Model.Items)
   {
      <input type="hidden" name="Items[@ind].Id" value="@item.Id"/>
      ind++;
   }
}
```

But id you can send the data by `Ajax`, in this case is mode simple, because you can create the data to send. See this plugin [toDictionary](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com.ar/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html)

Answer (score -1):

One way is to have the `List<SelectListItem>` as part of the view model and populate it via a method called from the controller and pass it to the view, e.g.

View model:

```
public List<SelectListItem> SelectList { get; set; }
```

And in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, Model.SelectList)
```